# $\beta^{+}$ and $\beta^{-}$ decay processes

Tags: nuclear-physics, neutrinos, neutrons, weak-interaction, proton-decay

We know that electron cannot exist inside the nucleus for various reasons like its energy, angular momentum violation and etc. But these $\beta^{+}$ and $\beta^{-}$ processes occurs inside the nuclei where a proton/neutron changes to neutron/proton releasing these $\beta^{+}$ and $\beta^{-}$ particles along with neutrino and anti-neutrino. Now from where these particles comes out? From inside the nuclei or outside of it and mainly, how are they form so that they come out?

Comment: "We know that electron cannot exist inside the nucleus for various reasons like its energy, angular momentum violation and etc." Huh? energy, angular momentum, momentum, etc. are all conserved in beta decay. Can you further explain what you mean by this because I'm pretty sure it's quite wrong.

Comment: Particles are destroyed and created spontaneously in [QFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%27s_interaction).

Comment: @AXensen, I mean free electron or electrons which are already existing. Like how are they form within them. Like can already electron comes out of it or what?

Answer (score 1):

> Now from where these particles comes out? From inside the nuclei
> or outside of it and mainly, how are they form so that they come out?

The electron and anti-neutrino (or positron and neutrino, respectively) come from within the nucleus.
But they were not existing there before. Instead they
are *created* in the moment of the proton/neutron change.
And then they fly away due to their large kinetic energy gained.
During this process the conservation laws (energy, momentum,
angular momentum, charge) are satisfied.
The intermediate [$W$ particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W_and_Z_bosons) shown in the diagrams below
are very short-lived ($\approx 3\cdot 10^{-25}$ s), i.e. they cannot
travel further than $\approx 10^{-16}$ m.
So the whole process takes place *within* the nucleus.

Quoting from [Wikipedia - Beta decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay#%CE%B2%E2%88%92_decay) ($\beta^-$ decay and $\beta^+$ decay):

> [image: beta- decay]
> The leading-order Feynman diagram for  $\beta^-$ decay of
> a neutron into a proton, electron, and electron antineutrino
> via an intermediate $W^−$ boson.

and

> [image: beta+ decay]
> The leading-order Feynman diagram for  $\beta^+$ decay of
> a proton into a neutron, positron, and electron neutrino
> via an intermediate $W^+$ boson.